# Source for the quotation, "More than Jews have kept the sabbath..."

Tags: sources-mekorot, song-poetry, quotations, literature

I have heard and seen in print many times the quotation attributed to [Achad Ha'am](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahad_Ha'am) that "more than Jews have kept the sabbath, the sabbath has kept the Jews" (exemplified in all its unattributed commonness [here](http://www.jewishtreats.org/2009/03/more-than-shabbat.html) and [here](http://he.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA#.D7.90.D7.97.D7.A8.D7.99.D7.9D), results of Googling). **Did he actually say or write this?**

I am not so interested in the source, as much as I am a yes/no answer to whether Achad Ha'am is its correct attribution.

Comment: Why [tag:song-poetry]?

Comment: @msh210 For all I knew when I asked, it could have been found in one of those.

Comment: @WAF For all you knew it might have been found in [tag:tractate-shabbat] or the [tag:rambam].

Comment: @DoubleAA Somehow, genrewise I assumed those to not be the case. Looks like I was on the money! Did you assume this was a talmudic or Maimonidean quotation before you saw its source?

Answer (score 6):

The original can be found in an article titled השבת וציונות authored by Ginzberg ([full text](http://benyehuda.org/ginzberg/Gnz051.html)).

> יותר משישראל שמרו את השבת שמרה השבת **אותם** (emphasis in the original)

Comment: How do you know the emphasis is original?

Comment: @WAF Original to the version in the link?

Comment: OK, but likely not to the author.

Comment: @WAF I don't know why you would say that. I agree it is possibly ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

[Per Sefer HaShabos - page 516](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41861&st=&pgnum=535&hilite=) this is attributed to Achad Ha'am.